# How to calculate the wing chord of the aircraft Aero A.10?

Tags: aircraft-design

Can anyone explain how to find the wing chord of the aircraft Aero A.10? Given Wing Span = 46.6 ft and Wing Area = 549 sqft. Thanks

Comment: `Can anyone please calculate for me`. uhm, no? we can teach you how to do it, but this website is not for solving your homework.

Comment: Okay, so can you please teach me howto calculate for the wing chord of this certain aircraft? Thanks Federico

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "please do my homework for me".

Comment: @VictorJuliet:  This is why we don't answer homework questions:  It just encouraged the poster to ask another question again, without putting forward any effort towards answering the question himself.

Comment: In the previous question he asked (which was closed of course because of its low quality), someone suggested him to post this as a seperate question, as this made more sense. Have a look at the comments on this: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16823/from-the-chosen-aircraft-calculate-the-lift-drag-tail-load-and-forward-inerti

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to calculate [...] the wing chord?

Given the data you provided you can only compute the SMC (Standard Mean Chord), that is equal to:

$$SMC = \frac{S}{b}$$

where $S$ is the wing surface and $b$ is the wingspan.

Answer (score 0):

Given the information in your question, it has to be assumed that the wing has a rectangular planform (because you mention no sweep angle and taper ratio). For a rectangular planform,

> span * chord = area
>
> chord = area/span = 11.78ft

Comment: Thank you so much. Wonder why people are so mean :( I just need help thats all :(

Comment: No Mark, you aren't asking for *"help"*.  You're asking for the answer.   *"Help"* is when you start with ***"Here's what I tried, the formula I used, why it didn't work, and why I'm stuck"***.  That makes for a complete effort and a good question.  You didn't do ***any*** of that.